# Netbeans' RESTful Java Client : javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException: HTTP 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: java, web-services, rest, post, netbeans

I'm developing a web service using **RESTful web service** of Netbeans. The service class contains following method:

```
@Path("jpost")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String jpost(Car c){
    return "Car:"+c.getTag()+"\t"+c.getName()+"\t"+c.getColor();
}
```

For testing this method, I'm using **Netbeans' RESTful Java Client** to generate test method. The result is:

```
public String jpost(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException {
        return webTarget.path("jpost").request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);
    }
```

When i call `jpost` following error appear:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.NotAcceptableException: HTTP 406 Not Acceptable
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.convertToException(JerseyInvocation.java:923)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.translate(JerseyInvocation.java:770)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.access$500(JerseyInvocation.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:671)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:422)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:423)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:326)
    at myserver.test5.jpost(test5.java:36)
    at myserver.MyServerTest.main(MyServerTest.java:32)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: The client does not specify a correct Content-Type. The only correct content type here is text/plain

Comment: Could you specify required changes in answer? I'm not familiar with RESTful client code generated by Netbenas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service only produces `text/plain` responses.

HTTP code 406 means that server cannot provide a content type acceptable by the client. So the client either specified a wrong content type in `Accepts` header, or did not send `Accepts` at all.

To specify the accepted type, `request(...)` argument is used.

```
public String jpost(Object requestEntity) throws ClientErrorException 
{
    return webTarget.path("jpost")
            .request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.entity(requestEntity, javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), String.class);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does Netbeans generate this incorrectly while I've set output format explicitly. Am i doing something wrong?